# send message from background script to content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage, content-script

I am currently running a chrome extension background.js script, Inside this script is a async function that runs in a for loop, In the middle of this function It goes to a url that then runs a content script

Here is what the for loop looks like:

```
var atc_count = 1;
for (i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
    console.log("waiting for getItem");
    await getItem(atc_count);
    atc_count++;
}
```

I am currently running a chrome extension background.js script, Inside this script is a async function that runs in a for loop, In the middle of this function It goes to a url that then runs a content script

During the middle of the function I want to send a message to the content script of the atc_count,  the content script takes the atc_count and does something with it

Here is what I have tried in the background script to send the atc_count to the content script:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.update(tab[0].id, { url: color_url }, () => { // tab.id
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {atc_count: atc_count}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.go);
      resolve("Updated the tab");
    });
  });
});
```

then tried receiving the message in the content script with this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(message.atc_count);
    sendResponse({go: "atc done!"});
});
```

This does not work.

I want to send the atc_count from the background script to the content script, when this content script recieves this message it is supposed to do something with the atc_count then when its done to sendResponse back and when the background script receives this (sendResponse) it knows that the content script finished and to continue its loop.

So I want it to use the content script once during each loop with only the atc_count changing using each loop.

Please lmk if you need any better clarification on my issue.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, and I hope you can help me. Thank you<3!

Comment: You're updating the tab (`chrome.tabs.update(tab[0].id, { url: ....`) which means that the content scrip is probably not loaded when you send the message.

Comment: so How would I get it to wait until the page has loaded? @Titus